# How can I find second key name in JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have below JSON message

```
[{"Num": 10, "SubLoc": "Chamr"}, {"Num": 34, "SubLoc": "angala"}, {"Num": 4, "SubLoc": "avano"}]
```

How can I find only the second key value i.e., SubLoc in the above case using javascript or jquery ?
I dont want to use hardcoded value in the javascript object because key value changes in each message.

**EDIT :** 
Below code can provide us the Key : Value data

```
jobs = [{"Num": 10, "SubLoc": "Chamr"}, {"Num": 34, "SubLoc": "angala"}, {"Num": 4, "SubLoc": "avano"}]

jobs.forEach(function(job) {
Object.keys(job).forEach(function(key) {
    alert(key + ':' + job[key]);
});
});
```

I just need the data of second Key i.e., "SubLoc" in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by find? Properties in Object are unordered

Comment: To display and later use as javascript variable  :)

Comment: Can you at-least show the pseudo code

Comment: added the code I'm using to fetch Key, Value data.. but I just need the Key data of second item (SubLoc)

Comment: `Object.keys(job)[1]` (i do not recommend that, due the lack of ordered properties)

Comment: Thanks Nina for your help!.. Can you please text the code without forEach loop ?

Comment: Then what could be the reliable way of fetching the second key data ('SubLoc' itself) using javascript ?

Comment: it is only possible when you make shure, that are only two properties and the one you will not have is named (and known), so you can exclude it.

Comment: yes.. I'm very sure about it. suggest me the code please

Comment: so you have always two properties and one of them is `Num`?

Comment: First key Num will be same in all the JSON messages .. but in the place of SubLoc, there could be other keyname.. like [{Num,SubLoc}, {Num,SubLoc}]  .. [{Num,Geo}, {Num,Geo}] .. [{Num,Diam}, {Num,Diam}]   etc.,

Comment: Yes Nina..  you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var jobs = [{ "Num": 10, "SubLoc": "Chamr" }, { "Num": 34, "SubLoc": "angala" }, { "Num": 4, "SubLoc": "avano" }]
var secondKey;
jobs.some(function (job) {
    Object.keys(job).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key !== 'Num') {
            secondKey = key;
        }
    });
    return true;
});
alert(secondKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqao54qu/1/) for this

```
var dataJson = '[{"Num": "10", "SubLoc": "Chamr"}, {"Num": "34", "SubLoc": "angala"}, {"Num": "4", "SubLoc": "avano"}]';

var data = JSON.parse(dataJson);



for (var eachObj in data){
    var keys = Object.keys(data[eachObj]);

    alert(keys[1] + ' : ' + data[eachObj][keys[1]]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I do not want to use hard coded 'SubLoc' as key data changes in JSON messages.. please read my request in the question.

Comment: My request is **not to get the value of key SubLoc which is 'angala'**.. I want **SubLoc** itself to be displayed without any hardcoded value in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs = [{"Num": 10, "SubLoc": "Chamr"}, {"Num": 34, "SubLoc": "angala"},{"Num": 4, "SubLoc": "avano"}]
var secondKeyValue = Object.keys(jobs[0])[1];
alert( secondKeyValue)
```

Comment: Hi Nahum, it works with this change.. var secondKeyValue = Object.keys(job)[1]; .. which gives us 'SubLoc' but this is in for each loop.. can you please suggest me without loop ?

Comment: How you can to iterate the array without loop? you must a for loop.

Comment: Hi Nahum, I just need second key data... example first JSON Message is  [{Num,SubLoc},{Num,SubLoc},{Num,SubLoc}] Seoncd JSON Message is [{Num,Geo},{Num,Geo},{Num,Geo}].. so, if you see the pattern, Num remains same as first key.. but second key changes.. in each JSON message, I would like to access second key. Therefore, I need the data of second key without any loop as all the second key values will be same in every JSON message

Comment: ok, so you need only the name of the second key, not the value. i will update my answer.